# How do I change the background on Twitter?

Tags: twitter

I see some pretty fancy user profiles on Twitter.

How can I change the background for my Twitter account?

Comment: Is https://support.twitter.com/articles/15357-customizing-your-design# helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the background from [the Design section](https://support.twitter.com/articles/15357-customizing-your-design#) of twitter settings.

- Head over to [Design Settings](https://twitter.com/settings/design) by clicking on your Profile picture → Settings → Design
- you can select a premade theme, or customize the Background image / position and the entering the background & overall profile theme colours